# How to track an application to determine what files are modified/created/deleted during the application execution on Linux?

Tags: linux

I searched the Internet, many of their advice is use "watch", such as:

```
watch -n 10 -d *command*
```

or

```
find directory -type f -mmin time -name filename
```

But they are for files changed by programs, not the files changed by a specific program.
Could you give any advice for me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about *strace*:

`strace -e trace=file <command>`

From the manpage:

> Trace all system calls which take a file name as an argument.

You can also do this for an already running process:

`strace -e trace=file -p <pid>`